# Sublime 3 PHP/HTML syntax highlighting

Tags: sublime-text-3, syntax-highlighting

[image]

This image sums it up. Whenever I write a PHP tag "inside" a PHP tag that ends in open brackets [if, else, for, ...], the rest of the line becomes white.

Comment: It's a bug, report it on the issue tracker: https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug that solved in build 3116, so make sure you update your sublime